# Xcode 9 Beta Build System fails with no errors

Tags: ios, xcode9-beta

So, this is strange. Trying to build my fairly large project with the new Xcode Beta Build System and it fails with 0 errors. The old build system works fine.

The status bar at the top of the IDE displays the following:

Planning build...
Scanning build tasks...

It has got further than this before, but now seems to be failing really quickly. No idea how I can debug this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to try these steps:

1. Quit Xcode
2. Delete folder ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
3. Reopen Xcode and try again

Hope it helps

EDIT: Quiting and reopening of Xcode after deletion of derived data is essential, because Xcode can hold derived data in it's cache. So deletion of derived data when Xcode is running does not help very often.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was the "unable to build node" error though due to files having the same name (an issue with a pod)

Comment: @magneticrob didn’t this show in the report navigator > build node? (command+9)

Answer (score 0):

Remove '**Derived Data'** before running the build.

To remove, go to

> **File > Work Space Settings > Go to the directory path > Delete.**

Do not forget to clean the project

**<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>k</kbd>**

Comment: Turns out it was the "unable to build node" issue that other people have mentioned.

Comment: Glad it solves that problem. Happy coding @magneticrob